# Is there any way to split a string into two lines in R?

Tags: r, string, paste, line-breaks, cat

I want to separate a string into 2 lines in R. I have found cat function, but it only prints to the screen. I need to assign the output to a variable.
For eg if my string is "Line1\nLine2", I need the output as following:

[Seperate to two lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKbtR.png)

Comment: You confuse output here with how it is stored in your variable. Your string format mentioned in your variable is correct.

Comment: If we are using cat function ( cat("Line1\nLine2, sep="\n"), we could get the output printed in two lines. I want that output to be assigned to a variable. Since cat function returns NULL, I couldn't do that. Is there any alternative way?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do. Maybe a bit more context would help.

Comment: Output is an output, storing data is in a variable is not output nor can you store output. You can output any variable though. So be more specific, I assume there is some place you want to actually output your variable. Let us know where. As the output will determine how it treats a line break.

Comment: I will explain  a bit more. I have a string "hello\nworld". I want to assign this to a variable say x, where hello in first line and world in second line.

Comment: I don't know what "lines" means. Variables don't really have "lines." They can have different places in a vector (e.g., c("hello", "world")) or different places in a list (e.g., list("hello", "world"), or different rows in a matrix (e.g., matrix(c("hello", "world"), nrow=2).

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to *display* x, shown below, on the R console as two lines then use either of these:

```
x <- "Line1\nLine2"

writeLines(x)
## Line1
## Line2

cat(x, "\n")
## Line1
## Line2
```

or if you are trying to *split* it into a character vector having two components then use one of these:

```
strsplit(x, "\n")[[1]]
## [1] "Line1" "Line2"

readLines(textConnection(x))
## [1] "Line1" "Line2"

scan(text = x, what = "", quiet = TRUE)
## [1] "Line1" "Line2"
```

or if you just want just the first part or just the second part then if y is any of the last three then y[1] and y[2] or any of the following:

```
sub("\n.*", "", x)
## [1] "Line1"

sub(".*\n", "", x)
## [1] "Line2"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any way to assign the cat output to an object?

Comment: No.  cat just renders the strings it is given onto the console.  If you want to create a new object consisting of a 2 element vector use the split options.  Be sure to distinguish between the object itself and its appearance when displayed.